# UITableView has different selection behavior on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I'm building an app for iOS 8. While implementing the selection handling I noticed that there is a difference in the behavior of the selection and highlighting handling between iPhone and iPad (tested it on the device as well on the simulator all running iOS 8.3).

Starting from a state, where one cell is already selected (and the table view only allows single selection). Cell A is the selected cell and Cell B is the new cell that will be selected.

On iPhone:

- Touch down:

  - Cell B -> set highlighted to YES
- Touch up:

  - Cell B -> set highlighted to NO
  - Cell A -> set selected to NO
  - Cell B -> set selected to YES

On iPad:

- Touch down:

  - Cell B -> set highlighted to YES
  - Cell A -> set selected to NO
- Touch up:

  - Cell B -> set highlighted to NO
  - Cell B -> set selected to YES
  - Cell B -> set selected to YES

The result is, that on the iPhone the currently selected cell stays selected until the touch ends. On the iPad the currently selected cell get unselected during the touch.

Does anybody know, if this behavior is expected or if it might be a bug?

Cheers,
Tobias

Comment: This is still the case as of iOS 9.2.1. Their table view implementation, shockingly, must uses something like `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` seeing as you can observe this incorrect behaviour in Apple Mail on an iPhone 6(s) Plus in landscape.

Comment: Filed as rdar://25164113, please file duplicates of ticket, if you agree this should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If this is indeed true, I can think of no reasons for it to be a valid scenario. Hence, it should be considered a bug.